# Php session not working in wordpress page template

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I have used session_start() in two templates of my wordpress site. In local server the i can able to use session variable in both the templates. 
But in live server i am unable to retrieve the session value. It shows blank array when i use
print_r($_SESSION)

Thank You

Comment: You can not use `SESSION` in WordPress without use of some plugin.
WordPress has restricted `SESSION` for some security..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress will allow only these Variables:-

```
'GLOBALS', '_GET', '_POST', '_COOKIE', '_REQUEST', '_SERVER', '_ENV', '_FILES'
```

`wp_unregister_GLOBALS` this function will reset your `SESSION` for some security reason. you can find this function in WordPress Package (`File:- wp-includes/load.php`)

You can find [Documents Here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_unregister_GLOBALS).

So, If you want to use `SESSION` than you need to use plugin for allow `SESSION` variable to use.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: And also try this:- http://silvermapleweb.com/using-the-php-session-in-wordpress/

Answer (score -1):

Place this code in your functions.php file

```
function ses_init() {
   if (!session_id())
   session_start();
}
add_action('init','ses_init');
```